# Used store credit in SQL database design

Tags: database, database-design

Consider these two use cases.

Say a store gives out store credit for customers. Store credit come from refunds, discounts, overpaying amounts etc...

1. The customer decides how and when to
   use this credit. E.g. Say customer A
   have $50 dollars in store credit and
   he decides to use $25 for invoice A
   and $25 for invoice B... or decides
   to have the store credit sitting
   there against his account for future
   purchases.
2. The customer and store must also
   have a way to look up the total of
   store credit.

**What is the easiest and most straight forward way to cater for this in table structure?**

I currently have tables:

- Transaction (For journal and reporting purpose)
- Customer
- Credit
- Used Credit

Invoice table will have other associations like invoice lines, receipt, receipt lines etc...

Is this the best way to do this? My concern is primarily regarding ease of reporting and transaction mechanics.

Alternatively I'm considering just saving all credit entry and used credit inside the transaction table.

**Updated diagram for clarification and from inputs**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you want something like this.

A `Customer` has `CreditEntry`s, and `CreditEntry`s have `UsedCredit`es. There are also `Transaction`s which include links to corresponding `Invoice`. And finally, a `Transaction` has links to many `UsedCredit`which were used during this transaction. If all CreditEntry was used at a time, then there will be one `UsedCredit` used with this `Transaction`, and this `UsedCredit` will correspond to the entire `CreditEntry`

The database schema would be quite straightforward here - relations through foreign keys. You would probably want to create an additional `unique` constraint to reflect `ONE-TO-ONE` relation between `Transaction` and `Invoice`

Oh, by the way, that [service](http://yuml.me/) that you used for diagram creation is cool.
[image: Diagram]

Comment: Thanks. Is the CreditEntry entity in your diagram the same as my UsedCredit? I'm assuming so...

Comment: One thing that I've left out is the receipt entity (Payment made against invoice). I was considering recording the receipt ID and receipt amount in the transaction table and this obviously won't work when we record used credit against transaction as receipt amount can include used credits...

Comment: @Rillanon - definitely yes, I have edited my answer. And isn't recipe amount always equals to the total number of `UsedCredit`s per transaction?

Comment: Well no, I define receipt amount as total of all payments for one receipt. So we can have multiple payments, A) Bank transfer B) Cash C)Store Credit etc... UsedCredit in my design refer to the part or all of the store credit that is used to pay part or all of the receipt...

Comment: In that case (once again, I feel I'm still missing the point) you could insert `Receipt` entity between Transaction and `UsedCredit`. Each `Receipt` could also contain a `value` - that would be the value of "no credit" payments. The total of each receipt could be calculated as `value` + sum of all `UsedCredit`s associated with that receipt

Comment: Great idea. I will use your suggestion and record receipt in transaction. This way I can easily look up receipts and balances all from one table!

Answer (score 1):

create 4 tables, 1 for customers then another for their credit and used credit and then another for transaction and invoice. You may join transaction and invoice since they may have similar data.

Comment: Thanks, but what you are suggesting is an improvement on my design. I'm seeking alternatives.

Comment: I should clarify, as from my previous readings, it was suggested to store credits and debit(invoice) in one table for ease of access. In that case I hope to expand that for my design to have store credits (credit), used credit (debit) and invoice (debit) all in transaction table but as I'm keeping a separate receipt (credit) table...

Comment: Oh, Ok. Depending on the size of the customer database and the transanctions that will take place you will need to sacrifice ease for performance. If the database is going to be fairly small then you can store this in two tables, else if it is going to be big then normalize the data to the third form. Nothing else. You structure seems fine.

Comment: Database will have 20k rows in each tables approximately.

Comment: Well, then I would suggest to keep with the normalized data structure.